# Mongoose saving and retrieving dates with UTC time, change to server timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, timezone

I'm using mongoose models to save my records including created and updated dates. Here's my model schema:

```
var CasesModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        caseId: Number,
        sessionId: String,
        createdAt: {type: Date},
        updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        docs: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    {
        collection: 'cases'
    }
);
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `updatedAt` field saves the datetime as `ISODate("2017-04-24T12:40:48.193Z")`, which is in UTC, but my server's timezone is `Asia/Calcutta`. Since I need to make queries according to my server's time, I need the datetimes to be saved in my preferred timezone.

Here's the query I need to execute (get all data for the last 10 days)

```
var today = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).toDate();
var tenDaysDate = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).add(-10, 'days').toDate();

CasesModel.findOne({updatedAt: {$gte: tenDaysDate, $lt: today}}, 
    function(err, caseData){
    cl(caseData, __line);
});
```

What I want is to do a query to get all the updated records in the last 10 days, exactly from 10 days ago midnight (`Asia/Calcutta` timezone) to today's midnight (`Asia/Calcutta` timezone). How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want is to do a query to get all the updated records in the last 10 days, exactly from 10 days ago midnight (Asia/Calcutta timezone) to today's midnight (Asia/Calcutta timezone). How do I do that?

If by "today's midnight" you mean the **last** midnight that happened (in which case you **will not** get results from a moment ago), then you can use something like this - using your local time zone:

```
// use moment-timezone to handle time zones correctly:
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

let end = moment().startOf('day').tz('UTC')
let start = end.subtract(10, 'days');
```

or explicitly using Asia/Calcutta time zone:

```
let end = moment.tz('Asia/Calcutta').startOf('day').tz('UTC');
let start = end.subtract(10, 'days');
```

If by "today's midnight" you mean the **next** midnight that will happen (in which case you **will** get results from a moment ago), then you can use something like this - using your local time zone:

```
let end = moment().endOf('day').tz('UTC')
let start = end.subtract(10, 'days');
```

or explicitly using Asia/Calcutta time zone:

```
let end = moment.tz('Asia/Calcutta').endOf('day').tz('UTC');
let start = end.subtract(10, 'days');
```

You will have UTC dates that correspond to your local midnights, ready to use in Mongo queries.

No need to change anything in Mongo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know storing timezone neutral time in the db is the correct and scalable approach, but just for my knowledge, could you tell me how do I save my local timezone in the dB?

Comment: @gaganshera There is not mush support for timezones in Mongo. See this Jira ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310