# SQL query in NodeJS hours are off when formatting date

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, date, formatting

I want to format the dtime2 field in my query: `SELECT FORMAT(MAX(dTime),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') FROM triangulations`

This gives the output  { result: [ { '': '03:34:30' } ], rowcount: 1 }

The hours should be 15. This is also displayed when leaving the format out of the query. Query: `SELECT MAX(dTime) FROM triangulations` gives output:

{ result: [ { '': Mon Jul 17 2017 15:34:30 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) } ],
  rowcount: 1 }

I execute the query in NodeJs with the library node-mssql-connector.

Why is SQL giving my the wrong hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your format string, `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, `hh` means you want the hours in the 12-hour-cycle format, so 3 and 15 are always 3 (AM and PM). Use `HH` to get them in the 24-hour-cycle format:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

[Relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), scroll down to the list of format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HH instead of hh:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX(dTime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') FROM triangulations
```

Comment: Me first :P Good job spotting it!

Comment: you are right, by 16 seconds before me :P (after some minutes it'll be shown as the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get bad hours while the minutes and dates are fine, in means that you're using the wrong time zone. This could mean that either the time in a wrong time zone was written to the database, or you're getting the date from the database in some other time zone that you're expecting.

You should always be explicit about time zones when working with dates (which you don't seem to be doing here when while putting the dates into the database), and it makes things much easier if you're always saving dates in UTC (which seems to be the case for the dates that you're reading here).

In Node you can convert the dates using the Moment module - Moment Timezone in particular. See:

- https://momentjs.com/timezone/

See this answer for some examples - it's about Mongo instead of SQL server but you can use exactly the same conversion here:

- [Mongoose saving and retrieving dates with UTC time, change to server timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590745/mongoose-saving-and-retrieving-dates-with-utc-time-change-to-server-timezone/43591331#43591331)

Comment: Then is it possible to format the dtime to the correct timezone within the SQL query?